# active admin adding paren't id automatically

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activeadmin

I'm using rails' active admin and working on a create screen for a model that belongs_to a parent. I'm getting an unpermitted_param error because activeadmin is automatically adding the parent's id to the form's parameters to be submitted. However, the parameter is being added outside of the model's hash. Here are the params submitted:

> {"utf8"=>"✓",
>   "authenticity_token"=>"9MBGkptu3jjLd4Zoy6lLUe1r6hW9TwRAmmiUNz2SwvQapRYv8nvOqZKWZKhgn9TEIXwNiD+IheQERVs+DpUgfA==",
>   "wedding_cake"=>{"client_id"=>"1", "first_name"=>"bob",
>   "last_name"=>"smith", "address"=>"11 big circle",
>   "city"=>"boston", "state"=>"ma ", "zip"=>"01234",
>   "phone"=>"1234567890", "email"=>"", "guests"=>"150",
>   "time"=>"12:30pm", "special_instructions"=>"", "package"=>"lake view
>   pavillion", "flower_price"=>"0", "rolled_chocolate_price"=>"0",
>   "other_price"=>"0", "tiering_price"=>"0", "deposit"=>"50",
>   "balance"=>"150", "vendor_balance"=>"0", "delivery_price"=>"0",
>   "consultant"=>"peter", "date(1i)"=>"2019", "date(2i)"=>"11",
>   "date(3i)"=>"18", "slice_price"=>"3.50",
>   "appointment_date(1i)"=>"2018", "appointment_date(2i)"=>"10",
>   "appointment_date(3i)"=>"16"}, "commit"=>"Create wedding cake",
>   "client_id"=>"1"}

wedding_cake belongs to client and should have a client_id (which it does). However, as you can see there is another client_id outside of wedding_cake. Here is the code I am using to generate the form:

```
form do |f|



inputs 'Venue Info' do
    f.input :client_id, :as => :hidden, :input_html => { :value => f.object.client_id } 
    f.input :first_name
    f.input :last_name
    f.input :address
    f.input :city
    f.input :state
    f.input :zip
    f.input :phone
    f.input :email
end
inputs 'Cake Info' do
    f.input :guests
    f.input :time
    f.input :special_instructions
    f.input :package
    f.input :flower_price
    f.input :rolled_chocolate_price
    f.input :other_price
    f.input :tiering_price
    f.input :deposit
    f.input :balance
    f.input :vendor_balance
    f.input :delivery_price
    f.input :consultant
    f.input :date
    f.input :slice_price
    f.input :appointment_date
end
f.submit

end
```

my strong_parameters are set up as such:

I have my permitted_params set as such in my activeadmin registration: `permit_params :client_id, :base_price, :first_name, :last_name, :address, :city, :state, :zip, :phone, :email, :guests, :time, :special_instructions, :package, :flower_price, :rolled_chocolate_price, :other_price, :tiering_price, :deposit, :balance, :vendor_balance, :delivery_price, :consultant, :date, :slice_price, :appointment_date`

Comment: This might be related to how your strong params are set up. Can you show us that code so we can see how the error is being caused?

Comment: I have my permitted_params set as such in my activeadmin registration: `permit_params :client_id, :base_price, :first_name, :last_name, :address, :city, :state, :zip, :phone, :email, :guests, :time, :special_instructions, :package, :flower_price, :rolled_chocolate_price, :other_price, :tiering_price, :deposit, :balance, :vendor_balance, :delivery_price, :consultant, :date, :slice_price, :appointment_date`

Comment: You should add the information as an edit to your original question

Comment: my regular controller has: `params.require(:wedding_cake).permit(:client_id, :base_price, :first_name, :last_name, :address, :city, :state, :zip, :phone, :email, :guests, :time, :special_instructions, :package, :flower_price, :rolled_chocolate_price, :other_price, :tiering_price, :deposit, :balance, :vendor_balance, :delivery_price, :consultant, :date, :slice_price, :appointment_date)`

Comment: Can you show the difference between your params and your strong params?  So  what is the difference between params, and permitted_params in your controller when the code actually runs?

Comment: Ok, so the difference is that there is a client_id OUTSIDE the wedding_cakes hash in params that is being added automatically by the form. HOW CAN I GET RID OF THAT?